# grunt-contrib-sass throwing "Could not find an option named" errors

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

All of a sudden, my grunt-contrib-sass task is throwing `Could not find an option named "sourcemap"` errors on build. I currently have sass 3.5.1 installed and using grunt-contrib-sass 1.0.0. Any ideas what could be causing this? Here's the output I'm seeing:

```
Could not find an option named "sourcemap".
Usage: dart-sass <input>
-s, --style         Output style.
                    [expanded (default)]
-c, --[no-]color    Whether to emit terminal colors.
    --[no-]trace    Print full Dart stack traces for exceptions.
-h, --help          Print this usage information.
    --version       Print the version of Dart Sass.
Warning: Exited with error code 64 Used --force, continuing.
Done, but with warnings.
Process terminated with code 0.
```

And, this isn't compiling down the CSS. Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you've installed dart and dart-sass is now what is being called for `sass` instead of the default, expected sass?

Comment: I'm thinking that's not it because if I run `npm list` I do not see it in the list. I do see npm ERR! extraneous: ruby@0.6.1 ruby-sass@0.0.3 and sass@1.0.0-beta.2. These are not in global either so I'm sort of confused.

Comment: Finally solved it. It looks like a bad npm pull caused my node_modules folder to be out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the node_modules folder and letting Visual Studio repopulate this folder.

Answer (score 0):

likely you have an old sass engine

try `sudo gem install sass`